# Is it possible to run CoreCLR on Windows XP?

Tags: .net, windows-xp, coreclr

Now we have a free open-source implementation of the .NET core: [CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr). It supports Windows and Linux operation system, Mac OS support is planned. Is it possible to run CoreCLR on Windows XP?

Comment: It is a building block, it needs to be hosted.  The provided sample hosts are very simple ones, intention is that people write their own to adapt the CoreCLR to their runtime environment.  You can perhaps write one for XP, you'll have to get it built first, wasting your time on a 14 year old operating system is your prerogative.

Comment: @HansPassant: I don't suppose it's his choice to support XP. I find myself in a similar situation where in 2018 I have to still provide compatibility with windows XP since that is what a number of our clients use. I would love to be able to get out of .net4.0

Answer (score 6):

I dont think so. The reason is as follows:
[image]
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library

Windows XP does not support any .NET framewrk higher than 4.0. and .NET 4.0 based winform apps or class libraries cannot reference .NET Core 1.x class libraries.

You might have better luck recompiling .NET core SDK, core clr & Corefx from sources for windows XP or any other operating system but I reckon its going to be very hard. If it were easier, MSFT would have done it in the first place.

About .NET CORE 2.0?[image: .NEt Core 2.0 support]
Reference: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md#technology-roadmaps

Answer (score 3):

Beware of the Turing tar-pit in which everything is possible but nothing of interest is easy. So it IS possible, but since XP might lack some low level APIs that are consumed in the Win 8/10 hosting implementation plus some native C/C++ compiler/target oddities, you could be in for a long road. Then again, is targeting XP for Core CLR really "interesting"...? ;)

Answer (score 1):

If possible. In fact, they already made it run on Windows 3.1, and even on MS-DOS.

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETEverywhereApparentlyAlsoMeansWindows311AndDOS.aspx

Obviously, it is not easy. You have to compile the .Net Core runtime, install the Win32s libraries, and various other things.